# Showing a geometric sum is 0

Tags: complex-analysis

If $x\ne y$ are integers, prove $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k}\left[Re\left(e^{i\left([x-y]\frac{n\pi}{k+1}\right)}-e^{i\left([x+y]\frac{n\pi}{k+1}\right)}\right)\right]=0$$.

I know that

\begin{align*}
&\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k}\left[Re\left(e^{i\left([x-y]\frac{n\pi}{k+1}\right)}-e^{i\left([x+y]\frac{n\pi}{k+1}\right)}\right)\right]\\[1em]
&=Re\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k}\left[e^{i\left([x-y]\frac{n\pi}{k+1}\right)}-e^{i\left([x+y]\frac{n\pi}{k+1}\right)}\right]\right)\\[1em]
&=Re\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k}e^{i\left([x-y]\frac{n\pi}{k+1}\right)}-\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k}e^{i\left([x+y]\frac{n\pi}{k+1}\right)}\right)\\[1em]
\end{align*}

Based on the hint I know that:

$$\sum_{k=1}^nz^k=\frac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z}-1$$

So if I let $a=e^{i\left([x-y]\frac{\pi}{k+1}\right)}$ and $b=e^{i\left([x+y]\frac{\pi}{k+1}\right)}$ then

\begin{align*}
&Re\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k}e^{i\left([x-y]\frac{n\pi}{k+1}\right)}-\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k}e^{i\left([x+y]\frac{n\pi}{k+1}\right)}\right)\\[1em]
&=Re\left(\frac{1-e^{i[x-y]\pi}}{1-a}\right)-Re\left(\frac{1-e^{i[x+y]\pi}}{1-b}\right)\\
\end{align*}

Then division of complex numbers is not simply the real part of the numerator divided by the real part of the denominator. So I have to break each fraction into its real and complex parts, perform the division and see what the real part gives and it should be 0. Unless there is a much simpler way I am overlooking.

So by complex division (note $Im\left(1-e^{i[x\pm y]\pi}\right)=0$)

$$Re\left(\frac{1-e^{i[x-y]\pi}}{1-a}\right)=\frac{Re\left(1-e^{i[x-y]\pi}\right)\cdot Re(1-a)}{Re(1-a)^2+Im(1-a)^2}$$

If $x\pm y$ is even then I'm done, ie $Re\left(1-e^{i[x\pm y]\pi}\right)=0$.
However, if $x\pm y$ is odd then $Re\left(1-e^{i[x\pm y]\pi}\right)=2$.
Then I have

$$\frac{2\cdot Re(1-a)}{Re(1-a)^2+Im(1-a)^2}-\frac{2\cdot Re(1-b)}{Re(1-b)^2+Im(1-b)^2}\ne 0$$.

Comment: I suppose you meant to say if $x \neq y$. Am I right?

Comment: Use $\sum_{k=1}^{n} x_{}^{n}=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$.

Comment: This doesn't seem right to me. If we take $k=1$, $x=y={1 \over 2}$ then the equation becomes $1-0 = 0$? (By continuity it is not true for nearby $x,y$ either.) Where did this equation come from?

Comment: yes I meant $x\ne y$ thank you, it's edited

Comment: @confused I'm guessing you meant $\sum_{k=1}^n x^k$. How is this applicable here? Doesn't this formula require $|x|<1$ and $|e|\not<1$.

Comment: To simplify your sums you can use $\sum_{k=0}^{n} x_{}^{k}=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$. It is valid for any $x \in \mathbb{C}$ (proove it by induction). Further as mentioned above, your equation doesn't look right. I guess lower limit of sum should be $k=0$. Further are your $x$ and $y$ integers ?

Comment: @Burgundy: The statement is not true as it stands.

Comment: @confused Yes they’re integers. copper.hat do you have a counter example?

Comment: The fact that they are integers is crucial and should be in the question, especially since x and y were the chosen variables.

Comment: @ZachBoyd thank you, updated